# Passing data between controllers gives an error due to complicated segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, segue

I have a modal segue which goes from a view controller to a tab bar controller which is embedded in a table view as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

I want to pass data between the login screen and the table view. I use the following code:

```
-(IBAction)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Enter App"]){
    //Pass on username so that app can set everything up for that specific user
    GamesListTableViewController *gamesList = (GamesListTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[GamesListTableViewController class]]) {
        NSLog(@"ENTERING PROPER CLASS");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"ENTERING WRONG CLASS");
    }
    gamesList.userID = self.userID;
}
}
```

My app crashes due to the last line of code. And i checked why (as you can see in the code above) and the reason is that the segue destination is not the GamesListTableViewController, but what i am assuming is the tab bar controller. How to i work around this problem?

Comment: The GamesListTableViewController is not the destination view controller, the tab bar controller is.

Comment: Yup, i got that, my question is how do i work around that, to send data from the view controller to the table view controller

Comment: Well, what are the relationships among those three controllers? Look at the properties that tab bar controller and navigation controller have relating to their children. You should be able to make a better attempt at it than what you show in your question.

Comment: I dont really understand what you are saying. The segues function fine,but I just thought there must be someway to pass data between the controllers without needing to create custom ones for the tab view controller and the navigation controller. Is that what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

```
UITabbarController *tabController = (UITabbarController*) segue.destinationViewController;
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*) tabController.viewControllers[0]; // or some other nr
GamesListTableViewController *tvc = nav.topViewController;
```